# PrestaShop: Get category name from webservice

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to get the category name from PrestaShop API.
But I'm failing to parse this xml object. I want to get the value "Root", but I don't know how to achieve this. From the PrestaShop data, I can get this data, how can I get the "Root" value?

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" } [0]=> string(4) "Root" }
```

This is my code:

```
$store_path = 'http://xxxx.com/';
$auth_key = 'xxxxxx';

$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($store_path, $auth_key, false);

// The key-value array
$opt['resource'] = 'categories';
$opt['display'] = 'full';
$opt['limit'] = 10;

//Retrieving the XML data
$xml = $webService->get($opt);
var_dump($xml[0]->categories[0]->category->name->language[0][0]);
```

Comment: What do you mean for root value? The ID?

Comment: The "Root" string that I printed in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$resource = $xml->categories->children();
echo $resource->category->name->language[0]->__toString();
```

Comment: node no longer exist.